# How to call a rest api and feed the result into a subsequent promise call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have the following code that calls a rest api and then uses the resultant data and feeds the values into a subsequent api call.  Not sure how to make this work..!  You can see my comment in the second method and this displays the data, but because it's a promise I'm not sure how to pass that back?

Any ideas?
Thanks

**Code snippet**

```
componentDidMount() {
  myMethod();
}


getBookings(id) {
    getCustomerBookings(id).then(res => {
        console.log(res);  // displays the data correctly
        return res;
    });
}    
myMethod() {
    var self = this;
    var myArray = [];
    getCustomers().then(result => {
        for(var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
            myArray.push(<div className="col">
                     {result[index].customerId}  // displays customer id as expected
                     {this.getBookings(result[index].customerId)} // attempt
                 </div>
            self.setState({customers: myArray});
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split this the single component into two - CustomerContainer and Customer, and tie the second API call to the mounting of the Customer component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class CustomerContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      customers = [] 
    }
  }

  async getCustomers() {
    // fetch customers
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    customers = await this.getCustomers();
    this.setState({ customers })
  }

  render() {
    const { customers } = this.state
    return (
      {customers.length > 0 && customers.map(customer => {
        return <Customer customerId= {customer.id} />
      })}
    )
  }

}

class Customer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bookings = []; 
    }
  }

  async getBookings(id) {
    // fetch booking
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    bookings = await this.getBookings(this.props.customerId);
    this.setState({ bookings })
  }


  render() {
    const { bookings } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="col">
        {this.props.customerId}  // displays customer id as expected
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: going to investigate this option and confirm back

Comment: I think I need to install `npm i -D babel-core babel-polyfill babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-0 babel-loader`, do I need this?  Thanks

Comment: You will need to add Babel as a dependency to use JSX and ES6 syntax

Comment: I've downloaded the library (mentioned in my previous comments).  I'm getting `regeneratorRuntime is not defined` as an error

Comment: Not sure of your requirements, but consider using create-react-app as an easy way to spin up a project: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
async myMethod() {
  var self = this;
  var myArray = [];
  var result = await getCustomers();
  for(var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
   var booking = await this.getBookings(result[index].customerId);
   myArray.push(<div className="col">
                     {result[index].customerId} 
                     {booking}
                 </div>

  }
 self.setState({customers: myArray});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are doing with `getCustomers()`, you have to get the result of the promise with `then`. So your code would look like this:

```
myMethod() {
    var self = this;
    var myArray = [];
    getCustomers().then(result => {
        for(var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
          this.getBookings(result[index].customerId).then(bookings => {
            myArray.push(<div className="col">
                     {result[index].customerId}
                     {bookings}
                 </div>);
          });
        }
    self.setState({customers: myArray});
    }); 
}
```

Note that this solution assumes you are not using ES6 `async/await` structure. Otherwise the other answers are better.

Comment: Your answer is good other than that there is no guaranteed order in the array since it depends on when each promise resolves, kind of like a race condition.